# How to transfer session variables throught domain django?

Tags: python, django, templates, session, subdomain

I have an multidomain app in django.

```
mx.myapp.com
nz.myapp.com
hn.myapp.com
```

and it works well. The problem is when I login in mx.myapp.com and some link have to redirect to nz.myapp.com the session variables are not set. How do I keep logged whith my account throught the diferent domains?

I think I have to transfer de session variables to another subdomain or something like that but I don't know how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify this in [`SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN) variable in `settings.py` file.

```
 SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.myapp.com' #for cross domain cookies
```

Don't forget the leading dot.